# TS2531: data possibly null when all alternatives are checked?

Tags: typescript

TS Playground: https://go.mpen.ca/39icg

Code:

```
enum ErrorType {
    PARSE = 'parse',
    SERVER = 'server',
    NETWORK = 'network',
}

type State<TData=any> = ({
    loading: true,
    data: null,
    error: null,
} | {
    loading: false,
    data: TData,
    error: null,
} | {
    loading: false,
    data: null,
    error: {
        type: ErrorType
        [k:string]: any
    }
}) & {abort: ()=>void}

function f<T>(): State<T> {}

function main() {
    const {loading,data,error} = f<{foo:string}>()

    if(loading) return
    if(error) return

    console.log(data.foo)  // Object is possibly 'null'.(2531)
}
```

If `loading` is false, then `TState` must either have `data` or `error`. If `error` is falsey, then it necessarily has `data`.

Why is TypeScript complaining that `data` might possibly be `null` in this scenario? I've checked both `loading` and `error` already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring your state into multiple variables. At that point, TypeScript will no longer type them together. Each is typed separately.

If you want this to work, you need to keep them together.

```
function main() {
    const state = f<{foo:string}>()

    if(state.loading) return
    if(state.error) return

    console.log(state.data.foo)  // no error
}
```